# Selectpicker (bootstrap-select) unfocus onchange

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, anchor, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using an hidden anchor to unfocus a bootstrap select on change like this:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="SelectAddress" name="SelectAddress" class="selectpicker" title="Select an address" data-header="Select an address">
    <option id="1" value="1" selected >First address</option>
    <option id="2" value="2"  >Second address</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#SelectAddress").on("change", function() {
//...mycode...
  $("#AFocus").focus();
});
```

The `$("#AFocus").focus();` makes unfocus the select picker but it also makes the to page go up. AFocus is at the top of page, so...

How to unfocus a select picker without using an anchor tag like my `AFocus` without scrolling the page ?

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ya0o7hzb/ Scroll down the page to see the bootstrap-select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bootstrap-select will add some HTML in the DOM like this:

```
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select"><button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="SelectAddress" title="Address 1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="filter-option pull-left">Address 1</span>&nbsp;<span class="bs-caret"><span class="caret"></span></span></button><div class="dropdown-menu open" role="combobox" style="padding-top: 0px; max-height: 297px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 37px;"><div class="popover-title"><button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">×</button>Select an address</div><ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" style="max-height: 248px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 0px;"><li data-original-index="1" class="selected"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="true"><span class="text">Address 1</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="2" class=""><a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="text">Address 2</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li></ul></div><select id="SelectAddress" name="SelectAddress" class="selectpicker" title="Select an address" data-header="Select an address" onchange="blur_picker('SelectAddress')" tabindex="-98"><option class="bs-title-option" value="">Select an address</option>
```

So you have to `blur()` the button containing the class btn:

```
$(".btn").blur();
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/93ohvn0j/

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This might do the trick.

```
<select id="SelectAddress" name="SelectAddress" class="selectpicker" title="Select an address" data-header="Select an address" onChange="blur_picker('SelectAddress')">
<option id="1" value="1" selected >First address</option>
<option id="2" value="2"  >Second address</option>
```

```
function  blur_picker ( element ) {
element = document.getElementById(element);
element.blur;
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately `.blur` does not work for a selectpicker.